# How to push to an std::stack in parallel?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

What is a simple manner to obtain push items in a list int[] to an std::stack in parallel?

Comment: What do you mean by "in parallel"? Do you want to use multithreading, or do you simply want to push all the integers onto the stack at once?

Comment: is there a way to push elements in a list at once? yeah, I want to know how to push several items fast. (instead of using for loops, I could do a parrallel call and push faster)

Comment: If using multiple threads you would need to use a mutex or some other lock to prevent multiple simultaneous access.

Comment: @user1730250: What do you mean by "parallel call"? Are you talking about threading or not?

Comment: I just want to know if this can be done in parallel or if it can be done in one step serially (using a memcpy or something like that)

Comment: Consider using an `::std::vector` which your `::std::stack` uses under the hood, anyway. If you do it right, you can "push" to it in parallel for whatever definition of parallel you end up having.

Comment: "Parallel" does not always mean "faster," especially when the operations are as fine-grained as pushing an element onto a stack of `int`. You could choose an underlying data structure in which appending a large number of elements at once is optimized (see the list-splicing answer below) while other operations are less optimized. But whether that's a good idea is not something we can answer in isolation, because you'd be making design choices that might make other parts of the code run slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "multi-push" elements from a list onto a stack, you can basically use the fact that a stack is just a container-adapter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stack>

template <typename T>
class My_stack final : std::stack<T, std::list<T>> {
public:
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::stack;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::push;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::pop;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::top;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::empty;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::swap;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::size;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::emplace;
    using std::stack<T, std::list<T>>::operator =;

    void push_elements(std::list<T>& l,
                       typename std::list<T>::const_iterator begin, 
                       typename std::list<T>::const_iterator end)
    {
        this->c.splice(std::end(this->c), l, begin, end);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list l{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    My_stack<int> st{ l };
    st.push_elements(l, std::begin(l), std::next(begin(l), 3));
    std::cout << st.top() << ' ' << st.size() << '\n';
}
```

Note that the insertion function moves the elements from the list to the stack rather than copying them, which should be very efficient. You can implement analogous functions basing on `deque` or `vector` as well using this scheme, whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you would consider this a loop, but you can use `std::for_each` and lambda

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>

int main() 
{
    std::stack<int> s;
    int list[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    std::for_each(std::begin(list), std::end(list), [&s](int i) { s.push(i); });

    return 0;
}
```